# How is $C_0^k(\mathbb R)$ defined?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I'm sorry for asking such a short question, but I see the space $C_0^k(\mathbb R)$ everywhere being used without a rigorous definition.

$C_0(\mathbb R)$ is the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ vanishing at infinity. The question is, is $C_0^k(\mathbb R):=C_0(\mathbb R)\cap C^k(\mathbb R)$ or is $C_0^k(\mathbb R):=\left\{f\in C^k(\mathbb R):f^{(i)}\in C_0(\mathbb R)\text{ for all }i\in\left\{0,\ldots,k\right\}\right\}$?

[Those spaces shouldn't coincide.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947675/derivatives-vanishing-at-infinity)

Answer (score 1):

Correct definition is that $C_0^k(\mathbb R):=\left\{f\in C^k(\mathbb R):f^{(i)}\in C_0(\mathbb R)\text{ for all }i\in\left\{0,\ldots,k\right\}\right\}$.

If you write $C_c(\Bbb R)$ set of all continuous function on $\Bbb R$ with compact support then $C_c^k(\mathbb R):=C_c(\mathbb R)\cap C^k(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I follow the notation of the book "PSEUDO DIFFERENTIAL OPERATORS and MARKOV PROCESSES" written by N. Jacob. See page xiv for notation.

Comment: $C_0(\mathbb R)$ can be defined to be the closure of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ in $C_b(\mathbb R)$ (bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$. Is in the same way $C^k_0(\mathbb R)$ the closure of $C_c^k(\mathbb R)$ in $\left\{f\in C^k(\mathbb R):f^{(i)}\text{ is bounded for all }i\in\left\{0,\ldots,k\right\}\right\}$ equipped with $\sum_{i=0}^k\left\|f^{(i)}\right\|_\infty$?